# Error: "The method orderby must be called before the method skip" when trying to do Inner Join for ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, listview, inner-join

Goal: Get information from two different sql server tables to display into a ListView. Most come from the User table, and one value comes from the UserRole table(particularly the "Description" field).

I have been working through a series of errors. The current one being:
"the method skip is only supported  for sorted input in linq to entities. The method orderby must be called before the method skip"
I've tried adding OrderBy to the queries, as all the SO posts mention, but I am still getting the error.

Question:  Should it(OrderBy) be somewhere else? And am I going in the right diretion or if there is a better implementation for joining two tables into a single ListView?

aspx:

```
    <asp:ListView id="lstUsers" runat="server" ItemType="Project.Classes.UserWRole" DataKeyNames="ID" SelectMethod="listUsers_GetData"
    OnItemCommand="lstUsers_ItemCommand" DeleteMethod="lstUsers_DeleteItem" OnSorting="lstUsers_Sorting"
     OnItemDataBound="lstUsers_ItemDataBound"
    ItemPlaceholderID="litPlaceHolder">

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>                            
                         <th>Username</th>
                        <th>TAX ID</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <asp:Literal ID="litPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
            </table>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>                
            <td><%# Item.UserName %></td>
            <td><%# Item.Tax_ID %></td>
            <td> <%# Item.Description %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

default.aspx.cs:

```
public IQueryable<UserWithRole> listUsers_GetData()
        {
            IQueryable<User> users = Project.Classes.Helper.UsersForUser(
                db: db,
                UserID: SessionManager.CurrentUserID,
                Search_User: Search_User,
                aUserRoleShortcut: SessionManager.CurrentUserRole
                ).OrderBy(i=>i.UserRoleID);



            IQueryable<UserRole> userRoles = db.UserRoles.OrderBy(i=>i.ID);

            IQueryable<UserWRole> myQuery = from user in users
                        join userRole in userRoles on user.UserRoleID equals userRole.ID
                        select new UserWRole{ ID = user.ID, LastName = user.LastName, FirstName = user.FirstName, OrgName = user.OrgName, UserName = user.UserName, Description = userRole.Description, Tax_ID = user.Tax_ID, DateAdded = user.DateAdded };


            if (users != null)
            {
                listNumSearchResults.Text = string.Format("{0} Results Found", users.Count());
                if (users.Count() > 10)
                {
                    ddlRecordsPerPage.Visible = true;
                    ltItemsPerPage.Visible = true;
                    ddlRecordsPerPage2.Visible = true;
                    ltItemsPerPage2.Visible = true;
                    dp1.Visible = true;
                }                   
            }

            return myQuery;
        }
```

UserWithRole.cs:

```
namespace Project.Classes
{
    public class UserWRole
    {
        public string LastName, FirstName, OrganizationName, UserName, Description, Tax_ID;
        public DateTime DateAdded;
        public int ID;
    }
}
```

helper.cs:

```
public static IQueryable<d.User> UsersForUser(d.ProjectPE db, int UserID, string Search_User, e.UserRoleEnum? aUserRoleShortcut)
        {
            IQueryable<d.User> users = null;                

            users = db.Users.OrderBy(a => a.LastName).AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Search_User))
            {
                users = users.Where
                     (a =>
                          a.LastName.ToLower().StartsWith(Search_User.ToLower()) ||
                          a.FirstName.ToLower().StartsWith(Search_User.ToLower()) ||
                          a.UserName.ToLower().StartsWith(Search_User.ToLower())
                     ).AsQueryable();
            }

            users = users.Where(a => a.IsActive).AsQueryable();
            return users;
        }
```

I expected to see the column from the second Table to show in the ListView, but instead I am getting these errors

Comment: Hi, can you try too add ToList() after the OrderBy(i => i.userRole) on listUsers_GetData()

Comment: @pascalsanchez I can add it to users and userRoles, but then query gives a type converstion error. When I try to change that to list, it says "UserWRole does not contain a definition for 'ToList' "

Comment: I think you should add stack trace and the method which contains `Skip()` method, because I don't see you're using `Skip()` extension method in current code. You can't use `ToList()` for `UserWRole` because it's a model class, not a collection class.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto When I search through the entire project, it does not find Skip() anywhere. " Matching lines: 0    Matching files: 0 "

Answer (score 0):

The following resolved the issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/order-the-results-of-a-join-clause

I usually do the method syntax, and didn't realize I was formatting the orderby incorrectly with the syntax for this join. I put the orderby in between the join and select and it works now:

```
join uR in uRs on u.URID equals uR.ID
                    orderby uR.ID
                    select new UserWRole
```